# How to add Customizable header in Adobe Experience Manager as a Cloud Service In dispatcher

Tags: apache, http-headers, aem, dispatcher, mod-headers

i want to add custom header in dispatcher configuration in Adobe Experience Manager as a Cloud Service I m adding this configuration

```
Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
```

when i m deploying the changes its not getting visible on dev domain
same thing is working on adobe managed services

I have tried multiple approachrs.
is there any specific file that we can set customizable header in Adobe Experience Manager as a Cloud Service?
E.g.: I m adding here \dispatcher\src\conf.d\available_vhosts
or we don't have access to do it to set headers

Answer (score 1):

You should add it into enabled_vhosts

/dispatcher/src/conf.d/enabled_vhosts/your_site.vhost

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try here: `/conf.dispatcher.d/clientheaders/clientheaders.any`

Comment: Yes i have tried in /conf.dispatcher.d/clientheaders/clientheaders.any in this path but can able to get visible on domain Same functonality is working on Adobe manage sevices 
but not working on adobe cloud as a service is there any different way to set header on  adobe managed cloud as a services

Answer (score 0):

try below code in your enabled vhost file:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
   Header always set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
</IfModule>
```